# Oracle SQL use variable in query string for JDBC executeQuery()

Tags: sql, oracle, variables, jdbc

I have to execute a query on Oracle using JDBC executeQuery() and want to use a variable in the query string like this,

`myVar = 'name'; select * from myschema.MyTable where EmpName = myVar;`

Please advise if this would be possible. I tried the DEFINE myVar and VARIABLE myVar methods per Oracle docs but got SQLException with both.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement and pass `myVar` in as a bind variable:

```java
String query = "select * from myschema.MyTable where EmpName = ?";
String myVar = "name";
PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement(query);
st.setString(1,myVar);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks @MTO however query string is read from an external file and the Java program executes it as-is. The goal is to avoid using same literal string all over the query and define it in one place.

Comment: @SeniorCoder Oracle forbids you from having two SQL statements in a single command (which helps prevent some SQL injection attacks). You either need to use: PL/SQL (but then you need to `SELECT ... INTO ...` something or use a cursor); or, combine both statements into one `select * from myschema.MyTable where EmpName = 'name'`; or put `select * from myschema.MyTable where EmpName = ?` in the file and then specify the value of the bind variable wherever it is used (as per my answer).